# Extra Question Votes not working

Tags: support, voting

I've tried for two days now to reach the new 40-vote limit (10 for questions).

The first day I voted for all things and got stopped before 40.

Today I voted for only answers until I hit 30, then tried to vote on a question and failed.

Is BCG not being updated?

Comment: I have just now tried this myself, twice in the last two days, I am above the 30 votes showing on my profile, but I still am not getting Vox Populi, it's freezing at 34/40..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that SE/SO decided to program in a little trick whereby you have to vote for the questions early, or you don't get all your votes.  You have be focused completely on balancing your votes or you'll get hosed.

Here's the reference: [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached/90734#90734).

I finally got it by making sure I voted for only questions (actually one answer vote slipped through).  It was so hard not to vote on a lot of the answers, what a sucky badge mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

It's working.  Or at least was working.

There are several folks with the [Vox Populi badge](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/badges/67/vox-populi).

Comment: I didn't even know there was a badge for that until I logged in one day and found it waiting for me.

Comment: @Little - it's less than a month old I believe.

Comment: maybe it has something to do with me not being in the commit for this site and being added in into the Private Beta, after the fact.